# Download a file in blackberry through application

Tags: blackberry

i need to download a video file from internet through my application. and i need to play the video through my application.

any code snipets or tutorial for this.. the application is in rhodes framework.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can just play the file directly from the server. The complete code is in http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Play-video-within-a-BlackBerry-smartphone-application/ta-p/445167

Comment: thanks jhonny i will go through the code but i need to run the video from offline also so i need to download the video to the phone and play it. the application in rhodes..

Comment: Then you can provide a URL to the file in the app. But if it's Rhodes I think you're better off using Rhodes' API. Check out http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps under "Media Support". Rhodes has an API both for media playback and asynchronous file download. Look at http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/call-web-services and https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes-system-api-samples/blob/master/app/Media/index.erb